# How to create a cmake libary project with config file?

Tags: cmake

I am completely stuck :/. I created a simple test "library" with two
files `fruits.cpp` and `fruits.h`.

Then I created this `CMakeLists.txt` (following this [tutorial](https://foonathan.net/2016/03/cmake-install/))

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(fruits_Lib)

add_library(fruits_Lib STATIC)

target_sources(fruits_Lib
  PRIVATE
    "fruits.cpp"
)

set(include_dest "include/fruits-1.0")
set(main_lib_dest "lib/fruits-1.0")
set(lib_dest "${main_lib_dest}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

target_include_directories(fruits_Lib
  PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${include_dest}>"
)

add_library(fruits::fruits ALIAS fruits_Lib)

install(TARGETS fruits_Lib EXPORT fruits DESTINATION "${main_lib_dest}")
install(FILES "include/fruits/fruits.h" DESTINATION "${include_dest}")
install(EXPORT fruits DESTINATION "${lib_dest}")
```

This works in that it compiles and installs etc, and I can even use
it as a `add_subdirectory` in a parent project.

In fact, the files that this installs are:

```
lib/fruits-1.0/libfruits_Lib.a
lib/fruits-1.0/Debug/fruits-debug.cmake
lib/fruits-1.0/Debug/fruits.cmake
lib/fruits-1.0/libfruits_Libd.a
lib/fruits-1.0/Release/fruits-release.cmake
lib/fruits-1.0/Release/fruits.cmake
include/fruits-1.0/fruits.h
```

However, when I try to do the following in the parent project:

```
find_package(fruits CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

I get the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fruits" with any
  of the following names:

    fruitsConfig.cmake
    fruits-config.cmake
```

Those files are definitely not created or installed by the above `CMakeLists.txt` :/.

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a static library that provides such config file
so that I can use it (after installation) with a `find_package(fruits CONFIG)` ?

Comment: In the tutorial you shared there is the section `The final step: Packaging` that explains how to include `config.cmake` file. Did you follow it as well? It looks like you are not installing that file: `install(FILES my_library-config.cmake DESTINATION ${main_lib_dest})`

Comment: Yes thanks. I added that and then got other errors (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is empty where they use it). So I forgot about that tutorial now and used cmake's documentation exclusively for building packages (I didn't know what those where!).  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Comment: could you, please, share your code, so I can give it a try? Maybe post it to github somewhere?

Comment: I will - I'm still working on it.

Comment: I was able to install and use library following the tutorial. I think that you had a build type missmatch and that is why it complained. Once build types match - everything works as expected. You can change build type ftom command line, e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

Answer (score 1):

I think `find_package()` is for locating and using **external** and already installed components/libraries so you'll have to install the library first.